# Setting "spacebar" to a HTML button

Tags: html, button, keyboard, click, space

is there a way to create a HTML button, which simulates space-bar pressing on the keyboard?

So, whenever I press space bar or click the button, I get the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be more specific. Why do you want to do this? To type out a space character somewhere?

Comment: No, I am developing a simple javascript game, and I have defined the space bar as a jump button. I would like to present it on a phone/tablet and I thought it would be much easier to simulate the space-bar-button rather than writing the touch tapping functions.